# not able to create a working change password page in php

Tags: php

so, I've a form for changing the password. I got everything running well except if the user puts his same old password in the new password area, it should return an error. I got the password hashed using password_hash(). 
I did the following but still if I just keep my old password on the new password area and hit the submit button, it successfully changes my password.

```
$sqlpw = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlpw);
$unhash_pw = $row['password'];
$new_password = $confirm_password = "";
$new_password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate new password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["new_password"]))){
        $new_password_err = "Please enter the new password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["new_password"])) < 6){
        $new_password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } elseif(trim($_POST["new_password"]) == password_verify($new_password,$unhash_pw)){
        $new_password_err = "Error, the new password cannot be same as old one!";
    }else{
        $new_password = trim($_POST["new_password"]);
    }
```

Form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($new_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label><b>New Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" name="new_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $new_password; ?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $new_password_err; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control">
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        <a class="btn btn-link" href="welcome.php">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Edit: Added the form code too.

Comment: you do not need the form action if posting to the same page and it is unwise to rely upon `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`

Comment: So, what could be possible solutions @ram

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saving the password in your table as is. When you are matching it using `password_verify($new_pass, $orig_pass)` it not going to match, hence no error.

```
$unhash_pw = $row['password']; 
... if(trim($_POST["new_password"]) == password_verify($new_password,$unhash_pw))
```

Also, the validation of password length, valid chars, etc. is better done before submission using Javascript. Users don't like doing it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a quick working demo ( without database ) to test this functionality. If the password in the database is indeed hashed correctly then you simply need the returned value from `password_verify` ( BOOLEAN ) rather than trying to test if it is equal to the new password itself

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        # use this password to test for a match
        $pwd_before_hash='banana';
        $hash_from_db='$2y$10$IKwRuWXehnpeexV65C6wY.iiPvj5m2USLoRs5lfumJSzNvbYK9RTC';


        $minlength = 6;


        $errors=array();
        $args=array(
            'new_password'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'confirm_password'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $field ){
            if( !isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) $errors[]=sprintf( 'The field "%s" is not set', $field );
        }
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Unknown field "%s"', $field );
        }
        if( empty( $errors ) ){
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );

            /* logic tests on supplied passwords */
            if( empty( $new_password ) )$errors[]='Please enter the new password.';
            if( empty( $confirm_password ) )$errors[]='Please confirm the new password.';
            if( $new_password && $confirm_password && $new_password!=$confirm_password )$errors[]='The passwords do not match';
            if( strlen( $new_password ) < $minlength )$errors[]=sprintf('The new password is too short - it must be at least %d characters long', $minlength );
            if( strlen( $confirm_password ) < $minlength )$errors[]=sprintf('The password confirmation is too short - it must be at least %d characters long', $minlength );


            /* compare hash - use returned BOOLEAN value!!! */
            if( password_verify( $new_password, $hash_from_db ) )$errors[]='The new password cannot be the same as your old password';
            else{
                if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                    exit( sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $errors, true ) ) );
                } else {
                    exit( '<br />OK-update the database with the new password' );
                }
            }   
        }
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <div>
                <label><b>New Password</b></label>
                <input type='password' name='new_password' class='form-control'>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
                <input type='password' name='confirm_password' class='form-control'>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Submit'>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $errors, true ) );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can appreciate if you can do any touch up with my code?

Comment: basically: `if( password_verify( $new_password, $hash_from_db ) ){/* password is the same*/} else{/* good - change pwd */}`